# Laravel - how to make a search filter with like anything in relationship columns

Tags: php, laravel, logic, backend, back

I'm trying to make a query where returns me the results, based on a request word, but I have to filter with the relationship columns as well. Example:

```
Payment::byUnity($unityId)
            ->with(['contract:id,nome,sigla'])
            ->latest('id')
            ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('contract.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('contract.description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->paginate(15)
```

How can I filter the "contract.name" on the query? Because the way of the example returns me error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `join()` syntax to make `contracts.name` available to query in your `where()` and `orWhere()` clauses. `with()` doesn't include that table in the base query, `join()` does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if I remove the "where" clauses, I can see the return with contracts with the "with()" with no problems. So, to make it "queriable", I have to do a "join()" after the "with()"?

Comment: `join()` instead of or in addition to `with()`, and position for that doesn't matter. You'd do something like `Model::join('related_table', 'related_table.related_id', '=', 'table.id')`, then you'd be able to do `->where('table.column')->orWhere('related_table.column') ...`. Or use the `whereHas()` logic in the answer below; either approach is valid 

Comment: Thanks! You guys rock!

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Payment::byUnity($unityId)
            ->with(['contract:id,nome,sigla'])
            ->latest('id')
            ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('contract', function($query) use ($request) {
                return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
            }
            ->paginate(15)
```

**NOTE:** You must have proper relationships set up for this query to work.